# Choosing between two Action.async blocks, why can't I specify Action.async in the caller?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, types, playframework, future

On the first line below, I want to know if there's anything I can or should put to the left of the `=` that will future-proof against bad editing.  I had one `Action.async`, but now I want to have two choices (run a single MongoDB query or run multiple MongoDB queries) to arrive at the answer to the web query `q`.  My code compiles as-is, but I think I should have to put something before the `=` to make the code more type-safe.

```
def q(arg: String) = 
  if (wantMultipleQueriesByDataSource)
    runMultipleQueriesByDataSource(arg)
  else
    runSingleQuery(arg)

def runSingleQuery(arg: String) = Action.async {
  if (oDb.isDefined) {
    val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = oDb.get.getCollection(collectionName)
    val fut = getMapData(collection, arg)
    fut.map { docs: Seq[Document] =>
      val docsSources = List(DocsSource(docs, "*"))
      val pickedDocs = pickDocs(args, docsSources)
      Ok(buildQueryAnswer(pickedDocs))
    } recover {
      case e => BadRequest("FAIL(rect): " + e.getMessage)
    }
  }
  else Future.successful(Ok(buildQueryAnswer(Nil)))
}

def runMultipleQueriesByDataSource(arg: String) = Action.async {
  if (oDb.isDefined) {
    val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = oDb.get.getCollection(collectionName)
    val dataSources = List("apples", "bananas", "cherries")
    val futureCollections = dataSources map { getMapDataByDataSource(collection, _, arg) }
    Future.sequence(futureCollections) map {
      case docsGroupedByDataSource: Seq[Seq[Document]] =>
        val docsSources = (docsGroupedByDataSource zip dataSources) map {x => DocsSource(x._1, x._2)}
        val pickedDocs = pickDocs(args, docsSources)
        Ok(buildQueryAnswer(pickedDocs))
      case _ => Ok(buildQueryAnswer(Nil))
    } recover {
      case e => BadRequest("FAIL(rect): " + e.getMessage)
    }
  }
  else Future.successful(Ok(buildQueryAnswer(Nil)))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to because Scala has [type inference](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/local-type-inference.html) in this case. But if you want, you can change the method signature to the following:

```
def q(arg: String): Action[AnyContent]
```

I'm assuming here that you are using Playframework.

**Edit**: In fact, in this case, [`Action.async` return an `Action[AnyContent]`](https://github.com/marcospereira/playframework/blob/3c1ac7a30926e402753232cd595a1d4c2a595dce/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L438-L438) and it receives a block that returns a `Future[Result]`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Playframework.  Thanks.  I added Future[Result] and I get "Expression of type Action[AnyContent] doesn't conform to expected type Future[Result]".

Comment: Sorry, I get confused by the block `Action.async` receives and its return type. I don't know how to make it clear here, so I left an "edit" note.

Comment: Thank you @marcospereira, that worked, and I also appreciate the explanation.